# How to obtain a non-trivial model of an idempotent quasigroup using Z3

Tags: z3

I am trying to obtain a non-trivial model of an idempotent quasigroup using Z3 with the following code

```
(set-logic AUFNIRA)
(set-option :macro-finder true)
(set-option :mbqi true)
(set-option :pull-nested-quantifiers true)

(declare-sort S 0)
(declare-fun prod (S S) S)
(declare-fun left (S S) S)
(declare-fun right (S S) S)

(assert (forall ((x S) (y S))
                (= (prod (left x y) y) x)))

(assert (forall ((x S) (y S))
                (= (prod x (right x y) ) y)))

(assert (forall ((x S) (y S))
                (= (left (prod x y) y ) x)))

(assert (forall ((x S) (y S))
                (= (right x (prod x y)) y)))
(assert (forall ((x S)) (= (prod x x) x)   ))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

but I am obtaining only a trivial model:

```
sat
(model
  ;; universe for S:
  ;;   S!val!0
  ;; -----------
  ;; definitions for universe elements:
  (declare-fun S!val!0 () S)
  ;; cardinality constraint:
  (forall ((x S)) (= x S!val!0))
  ;; -----------
  (define-fun elem!3 () S
    S!val!0)
  (define-fun elem!2 () S
    S!val!0)
  (define-fun elem!0 () S
    S!val!0)
  (define-fun elem!1 () S
    S!val!0)
  (define-fun left ((x!1 S) (x!2 S)) S
    S!val!0)
  (define-fun right ((x!1 S) (x!2 S)) S
    S!val!0)
  (define-fun prod ((x!1 S) (x!2 S)) S
    x!1)
)
```

Run this example online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/dx9Q)

Please let me know how we can obtain a non-trivial model.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want to find more than one sat model for the original assertions.

I have a dull solution here. You can define another set of functions in the same way as prod, left and right, which are named prod2, left2 and right2. Add assertions for them similarly. Then, you want prod2 to differ from prod.

Like this:

```
(assert (exists ((x S) (y S)) (not (= (prod x y) (prod2 x y)))))
```

or maybe expression meaning or(prod != prod2, left != left2, right != right2) will be more proper.
I took a little attempt to run that online, but returned 'time out'. I think you have to do it on your machine.

This may be not a best answer, but best regards!